# How to test callbacks in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: flask, callback, openapi

I see that OpenAPI 3.0 has released callback capability and I'm struggling to understand how to properly use it.

I'm a bit new to API development, so I began using this [example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/callback-example.yaml). I generated a Python Flask server. Just for testing purposes, I input the `callbackUrl` to be the same localhost that I'm running the Flask server when I do the initial POST. This is to say, I'm testing with the following POST request URL:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5050/streams?callbackUrl=0.0.0.0%3A5050
```

When I run this it does give me a 200 response, but I'm actually interested in understanding how I can see the JSON response with the subscription payload, which I thought would be located at

```
http://0.0.0.0:5050/data
```

However, when I hit this it doesn't appear to be the case. Can anyone help me out?